# How to fix error :" AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'contrib' " on Windows

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, object-detection-api

I have a source code read CAPTCHA. When i run test, I got a problem on Windows 10

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 48, in <module>
    from object_detection.builders import dataset_builder
  File "C:\Users\HuyHys\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\object_detection\builders\dataset_builder.py", line 27, in <module>
    from object_detection.data_decoders import tf_example_decoder
  File "C:\Users\HuyHys\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\object_detection\data_decoders\tf_example_decoder.py", line 27, in <module>
    slim_example_decoder = tf.contrib.slim.tfexample_decoder
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'contrib'
```

I found a ask on stackoverflow (visit [Module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'contrib'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55870127/module-tensorflow-has-no-attribute-contrib))

But i can't fix this error. Pls, anyone can help me!
How to fix detail this error???

Comment: In your link to the other answer there are several good solutions to try. What exactly is your problem? What have you tried and it didn't work?

Comment: i got error when i'm setting environment

Comment: I got this error with only windows. On ubuntu, i got other errors

Answer (score 2):

This Error occurs because `tf.contrib` is removed from TensorFlow 2. I guess you are using old code from Tensorflow 1 that is not compatible with the new Tenserflow 2. For more  information checkout [Migrate your TensorFlow 1 code to TensorFlow 2](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate). If you need more help please share all code snippets where you use `tf.contrib`.