# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'get_variable'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning

**I am trying to run this line of code :**

```
var_init_1 = tf.get_variable("var_init_1", [1, 2], dtype=tf.int32,  initializer=tf.zeros_initializer)
print(var_init_1.shape)
```

It should give an output the shape of tensor of zeros.

### **But why I'm getting an error like this:**

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-3cc73aa1818e> in <module>
----> 1 var_init_1 = tf.get_variable("var_init_1", [1, 2], dtype=tf.int32,  initializer=tf.zeros_initializer)
      2 print(var_init_1.shape)

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'get_variable'
```

Comment: You're probably using TF2. TF2 doesn't support get_variable() anymore (supports only for compatibility reasons `tf.compat.v1.get_variable`)

Comment: I've installed tenserflow using "pip3 install tenserflow",  should i upgrade it?

Comment: you need to downgrade to 1.X version

Comment: thanks for your help downgrading worked !!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Replace tf.get_variable with tf.Variable.

Comment: (which NB has different argument syntax)

Comment: This is not working for me. Not sure why it's accepted answer. Another method worked by converting v1 to v2:  tf_upgrade_v2 \
--intree my_project/ \
--outtree my_project_v2/ \
--reportfile report.txt

Answer (score 3):

Mentioning the Solution for the benefit of the community.

Downgrading to Tensorflow `1.X Version (1.14 or 1.15)` has resolved the issue, as `Tensorflow` version `2.0` doesn't support `get_variable()`.

Answer (score 3):

tf.Variable does not work for initilizer. Use this instead of `tf.compat.v1.get_variable` instead of `tf.Variable`. This works tensorflow 2.0 and above.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem and other issue with tf v1 vs. tf v2. I found the best solution is proposed at this overstock link: [Module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'contrib'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55870127/module-tensorflow-has-no-attribute-contrib)

```
$tf_upgrade_v2 \
--intree my_project/ \
--outtree my_project_v2/ \
--reportfile report.txt
```

Basically you just convert tf v1 project to tf v2. Most of the time it will work. You do need to inspect get_variable conversion and make sure it's what you want. Examine report.txt on how it's converted.