# Python 3.5 - AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'contrib'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have the following function:

```
def build_estimator(model_dir, model_type):
    """Build an estimator."""

    # Wide columns and deep columns.
    wide_columns = []

    deep_columns = []

    for c in COLUMNS:
        # Sparse base columns.
        print(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>")
        print(c)
        column = tf.contrib.layers.sparse_column_with_hash_bucket(c, hash_bucket_size=10000)
        deep_columns.append(tf.contrib.layers.embedding_column(column, dimension=8))
        #wide_columns.append(column)

    if model_type == "wide":
        m = tf.contrib.learn.LinearClassifier(model_dir=model_dir, 
                                              feature_columns=wide_columns)
    elif model_type == "deep":
        m = tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier(model_dir=model_dir, 
                                           feature_columns=deep_columns, 
                                           hidden_units=[100, 50])
    else:
        m = tf.contrib.learn.DNNLinearCombinedClassifier(
            model_dir=model_dir,
            linear_feature_columns=wide_columns,
            dnn_feature_columns=deep_columns,
            dnn_hidden_units=[100, 50])

    return m
```

But when I run it, I get this exception:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "ad_tf.py", line 336, in 
>   main([sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
>   File "ad_tf.py", line 218, in main
>   m = build_estimator(model_dir, 'wide_n_deep')
>   File "ad_tf.py", line 58, in build_estimator
>   column = tf.contrib.layers.sparse_column_with_hash_bucket(c,
>   hash_bucket_size=10000)
>   AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'contrib'

I tried using tensorflow 1.x but it didn't dix anything. What is the replacement to contrib?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55870127/module-tensorflow-has-no-attribute-contrib?rq=1

Comment: I tried applying the solution in the above question, but it didn't work for me.

Comment: What exactly did you try? What versions of TF have you tried it on?

Comment: TF 2 and TF 1.4

Answer (score 0):

TF.contrib is removed from Tfv 2.x. It is recommended to use latest Tensorflow version 2.x.
Convert your code from Tf1.x to Tf 2.x by following [migration guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate)

Remove old `tf.contrib.layers` and replace them with [TF Slim](https://github.com/google-research/tf-slim) symbols. Also check [TF Addons](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons) for other tf.contrib symbols.