# R Tensorflow - how to upgrade to tf v2

Tags: r, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am attempting to use tensorflow to train a GAN in R. I'm getting the following error

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'contrib'
```

I've been searching for a solution and found this question
[Module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'contrib'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55870127/module-tensorflow-has-no-attribute-contrib) which tells me that my code is using TF 1.X syntax.

This directs me to the `tf_upgrade_v2` script, however it seems to be oriented towards python scripts. Is there a way to upgrade my R script?

Comment: I have the same issue.