# unable to use tf.contrib

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, lstm, attributeerror

I imported tensorflow module but I'm unable to use tf.contrib.
I don't know what the problem is.
I tried running it in different versions but I keep getting the same output.

ModulesImported:

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf1
tf1.disable_v2_behavior() 
import tensorflow as tf2
```

Code:

```
tf2.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(num_units=num_nodes[li],
                            state_is_tuple=True,
                            initializer= tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()
                           )
```

Output:

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'contrib'
```

Comment: I think [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55870127/module-tensorflow-has-no-attribute-contrib) maybe help you!
I hope it works you
Best!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the problem is in the version, i have tried it in 1.15.2 version and it worked for me.
After installing the mentioned version try the below code, it should work.

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf1
tf1.disable_v2_behavior() 
import tensorflow as tf2 #Tensorflow 1.15.2
from tensorflow.contrib.rnn import LSTMCell


LSTMCell(num_units=num_nodes[li],
                            state_is_tuple=True,
                            initializer= tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()
                           )
```

But if you are using TensorFlow 2.x version contrib has been deprecated, you can use the below code. Since **xavier_initializer** is also is using contrib you can use **GlorotUniform** initializer which is the same as **xavier_initializer**.
Follow the below code.

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf1
tf1.disable_v2_behavior() 
import tensorflow as tf2 #Tensorflow 2.x

tf2.compat.v1.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(num_units=10,
                            state_is_tuple=True,
                            initializer= tf2.initializers.GlorotUniform()
                           )
```