# neural_style.py AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'value'

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

So I've been changing a code of someone else to make my computer deep dream because it didn't work, I already solved a couple errors but I'm not able to fix this one.
Thanks in advance.

THIS IS THE ORIGINAL GITHUB PROJECT
https://github.com/cysmith/neural-style-tf

THIS IS THE ERROR I GET

```
  File "E:\anaconda\neural-style-tf-master\neural_style.py", line 362, in style_layer_loss
    M = h.value * w.value
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'value'
```

THIS IS THE CODE AROUND LINE 362

```
def style_layer_loss(a, x):
  _, h, w, d = a.get_shape()
  M = h.value * w.value
  N = d.value
  A = gram_matrix(a, M, N)
  G = gram_matrix(x, M, N)
  loss = (1./(4 * N**2 * M**2)) * tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow((G - A), 2))
  return loss
```

THIS IS MY PARTIALLY REPROGRAMMED VERSION OF neural_style.py

https://github.com/nicolai256/ERROR/blob/master/neural_style.py

Comment: Instead of `value` try `values`. Let me know if that doesn't work and I'll try something else.

Comment: if ```h``` or ```w``` are ints, then you need to use their values by just using the variable name without the ```.value``` part.  That said, I'm not entirely convinced that is the solution since without knowing what get_shape() is returning, it's hard to judge if just removing ```.value``` is the right solution.

Comment: I changed all the '''value''' codes into '''values''' but I still get the same error

Comment: I deleted all the .value parts and I don't get the same error anymore but I get another error now...          File "E:\anaconda\neural-style-tf-master\neural_style.py", line 624, in get_optimizer
    optimizer = tf.contrib.opt.ScipyOptimizerInterface(
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'contrib'.

Comment: It sounds like you’re trying to run a script for Tensorflow 1.x using Tensorflow 2.0.  See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55870127/module-tensorflow-has-no-attribute-contrib

Comment: so if i downgrade my tensorflow to 1.x the script should run fine?

Comment: Please avoid block capitals (let alone in **bold**)...