# This version of TensorFlow Probability requires TensorFlow version >= 2.3

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I tried to run a model using TensorFlow Probability.
But when I run it I got the error below:

```
**ImportError: This version of TensorFlow Probability requires TensorFlow version >= 2.3; Detected an installation of version 2.0.0-beta1. Please upgrade TensorFlow to proceed.**<br>
```

I cannot install TensorFlow 2.3 because it says there is no match.
I have installed these libraries.

> **tensorflow (2.0.0b1)
>  tensorflow-estimator (1.14.0)
>  tensorflow-tensorboard (1.5.1)
>  tfp-nightly
> (0.12.0.dev20200817)**

Any suggestion how to fix it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error indicates, you must have a version of TensorFlow >= 2.3 to use tensorflow-probability.
Update it to 2.4, if you work with 'pip':

`pip install tensorflow==2.4`

Answer (score 7):

If you did not want to upgrade tensorflow (while my tf version is 2.5.0) then specify the version for tensorflow_probability while installing like:

```
pip install tensorflow_probability==0.12.2
```

this works for me.

Comment: how one can see version of `tensorflow` corresponds to which version of `probability`?

Comment: @BoppityBop https://github.com/tensorflow/probability/releases here.

Answer (score 1):

If you did not want to upgrade `tensorflow`, you can uninstall tfp and then `pip install tensorflow==0.10` which will work (while my enviroment `tf==2.2.0`)