# How to add 'contrib' attribute into module tensorflow 2.9?

Tags: python, tensorflow, attributes

I am a newbie in **tensorflow**, just started a week ago. I was trying to run `tf.contrib.slim`, however, I was told that `"AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'contrib'"`. Anyone has solved this problem before and lend me a help? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

> `tf.contrib` has moved out of TF starting TF 2.0 alpha.

This question was already answered by @mlneural03

More information can be found under the original question: [Module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'contrib'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55870127/module-tensorflow-has-no-attribute-contrib)

The Tensorflow 2.0 release notes: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases/tag/v2.0.0-alpha0

In the linked post it is also explained how to get around this issue on Tensorflow 2.x+. This (for example) is a way to automatically upgrade your code from TF1 to TF2:

```
$tf_upgrade_v2 \
--intree my_project/ \
--outtree my_project_v2/ \
--reportfile report.txt
```

The equivalent to `tf.contrib` would be `tf.compat.v1.estimator`.

Comment: Yes, im able to solve the prob. Thank you!