# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'contrib' Tensorflow Object Detection API

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, object-detection-api

when I try to run the verification script for the Tensorflow object detection model api  I get the following error: AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'contrib'.
I have Tensorflow 2.13.0 and I am running my verification script 'model_builder_tf2_test.py' so it should run for also Tensorflow 2.

I have read in other sites that tensorflow 2 has not the attribute contrib but I have seen other tutorials and this error does not show up to anybody. And I am testing on model_builder_tf2_test.py so for tensorflow 2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'contrib'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55870127/module-tensorflow-has-no-attribute-contrib)