# tf.contrib.slim , AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'contrib'

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, object-detection, slim

*Code Snippet:*

import functools
import tensorflow as tf
from object_detection.core import box_predictor
from object_detection.utils import static_shape

slim = tf.contrib.slim

*Error Message:*

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:\uav\TFODCourse\Tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\builders\model_builder_tf2_test.py", line 24, in 
from object_detection.builders import model_builder
File "E:\uav\TFODCourse\tfod\lib\site-packages\object_detection\builders\model_builder.py", line 22, in 
from object_detection.builders import box_predictor_builder
File "E:\uav\TFODCourse\tfod\lib\site-packages\object_detection\builders\box_predictor_builder.py", line 22, in 
from object_detection.predictors import mask_rcnn_box_predictor
File "E:\uav\TFODCourse\tfod\lib\site-packages\object_detection\predictors\mask_rcnn_box_predictor.py", line 21, in

slim = tf.contrib.slim
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'contrib'

I am running a Custom Object Detection Model on Jupyter Notebook for tensorflow version of 2.15.0<=.

Can anyone help me to debug the error without switching to TF1.X?
Thank You

I have tried the solution provided earlier on the forum regarding the same i.e. to downgrade from TF2.0 to TF1.0 and like wise every solution but getting the same error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'contrib'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55870127/module-tensorflow-has-no-attribute-contrib)